# Why can't I enter this date into a table using sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Structure of the employee table:

```
 Name          Null?    Type
 ------------- -------- ------------
 EMPLOYEE_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 FIRST_NAME             VARCHAR2(50)
 LAST_NAME              VARCHAR2(50)
 EMAIL                  VARCHAR2(50)
 DEPT_ID                NUMBER(38)
 SALARY                 NUMBER(38)
 COMMISION_PCT          FLOAT(126)
 HIREDATE               DATE
```

`INSERT` statement :

```
insert into employees_table
values (05,'Sophie','Kuchinskey','sophiekuchinskey@yahoo.com',105,5000000,60,'20-sept-1994');
```

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Comment: It will help if you show what the structure of employees_table is

Comment: `to_char('20-SEP-1994', 'dd-Mon-yyyy')`

Comment: The date format you're trying to use isn't recognized/supported. It's possibly parsing them as `y-m-d`, seeing `20` as an invalid year.

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi: Not `to_char` but `to_date` since you want a date. A date literal is another way to go. See the answer by MT0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please convert the date into correct date format

```
insert into employees_table values(05,'Sophie','Kuchinskey','sophiekuchinskey@yahoo.com',105,5000000,60,to_date('20-sep-1994','dd-Mon-YYYY'));
```

Also you can't give month as sept . it should be sep.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle will do an implicit `TO_DATE` on non-date literals when inserting them into a `DATE` column using the value of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as the format mask. If the non-date literal matches this format then it will work (and if it doesn't then it won't) - however, if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is ever changed then it will immediately break (any be a huge pain to debug as the code that was working won't but no-one will have changed the code).

You can find out your current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` with the query:

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE  PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

It is better to explicitly use `TO_DATE` with the correct format mask or to use an ANSI date literal (i.e. `DATE '2014-12-01'`).

```
insert into employees_table
values(
  05,
  'Sophie',
  'Kuchinskey',
  'sophiekuchinskey@yahoo.com',
  105,
  5000000,
  60,
  TO_DATE( '20-sep-1994', 'DD-Mon-YYYY' )
);
```

Or, using locale/language agnostic ANSI format:

```
insert into employees_table
values(
  05,
  'Sophie',
  'Kuchinskey',
  'sophiekuchinskey@yahoo.com',
  105,
  5000000,
  60,
  DATE '1994-09-20'
);
```