# SQL Date Format Conversion

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question regarding SQL dates.
The table I am working with has a date field in the following format: "22-SEP-08". The field is a date column.

I am trying to figure out how to output records from 1/1/2000 to present day.

The code below is not filtering the date field:

```
Select distinct entity.lt_date 
from feed.entitytable entity 
where entity.lt_date >= '2000-01-01'
```

Any help regarding this issue is much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I am using Oracle SQL Developer to write my code.

Comment: Is your date field actually declared as a `DATE` datatype?

Comment: what database are you using? Oracle, MSSQL, MySQL, DB2?

Comment: If this is Oracle you can wrap TO_DATE() around it and see.

Comment: Yes I am using Oracle SQL Developer to write this code.

Comment: OK, but what is the database type, these date functions differ among implementations. You can use SQL developer to connect to different types

Comment: On Oracle maybe you can use the function TO_DATE(date_col, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS AM') and to get the present day use GETDATE()

Comment: I feel like the error is in the where statement, it just isn't filtering the data at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I enter this date into a table using sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149206/why-cant-i-enter-this-date-into-a-table-using-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DATEs do ***not*** have "a format". Any format you *see* is applied by the application *displaying* the date value.

You can either change the configuration of SQL Developer to display dates in a different format, or you can use `to_char()` to format the date the way you want.

---

The reason your statement does not work, is most probably because of the implicit data type conversion that you are relying on.

`'2000-01-01'` is a string value, not a date. And the string is converted using the NLS settings of your session. Given the fact that you see dates displayed as `DD-MON-YY` means that that is the format that is used by the evil implicit data type conversion. You should supply date values **always** as real date literals.

There are two ways of specifying a *real* date literal. The first is ANSI SQL and simple uses the keyword `DATE` in front of an ISO formatted string:

```
where entity.lt_date >= DATE '2000-01-01'
```

Note the `DATE` keyword in front of the string, wich makes it a real date literal not a string expression.

The other option is to use `to_date()` to convert a character value into a date:

```
where entity.lt_date >= to_date('2000-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

More details about specifying date literals can be found in the manual:

- [Date literals](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062)
- [to_date function](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132)

Comment: +1. To shed a little more light on what's happening in the original query.  There's an implicit datatype conversion going on, from the  DATE datatype of the column to VARCHAR to get a string the Oracle can compare to the string literal.  And Oracle is using the setting of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter as the second argument of the implicit `TO_CHAR` function. This answer has the right "fix".

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the data type isn't a Date. Just in case its a char type, try to convert it using the Oracle TO_DATE() function. The Oracle documentation below should help you with parameters.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

Comment: You're right, sort of. The datatype of the column is DATE. The datatype of the string literal is *not* DATE. Using the `TO_DATE` function on the string literal is the fix.

Answer (score 0):

**An implicit datatype conversion bites once again.**

You're right. The predicate is not doing the comparison you are expecting,

Oracle is performing an *implicit* datatype conversion, from `DATE` to `VARCHAR`, so that it can do a comparison to the string literal.

If `lt_date` column is `DATE` datatype, then Oracle is seeing your `where` clause:

```
 where entity.lt_date >= '2000-01-01'
```

Oracle is actually seeing it as if it's written like this:

```
 where TO_CHAR(entity.lt_date) >= '2000-01-01'
```

And that's where the "format" problem comes in. The column itself does *not* have a "format". Because the second argument to the `TO_CHAR` function is not supplied, Oracle is using the value of the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter (from your session). And that's probably set to `DD-MON-YY`.  Which is why that's the "format" you're seeing when you a run a SELECT statement in SQL*Plus. Because the `DATE` value is (again) being run through a `TO_CHAR` function to get a string that can be displayed.

To get the "filtering" you want, don't do a comparison to a string literal. Instead, do the comparison to an expression that has `DATE` datatype.

You can use the Oracle `TO_DATE` function. And you don't want to rely on setting of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, explicitly specify the format model as the second argument to the function. For example:

*DO THIS*

```
where entity.lt_date >= TO_DATE('2000-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

---

*DON'T DO THIS*

It's also possible to specify the format model as the second argument to the `TO_CHAR` function.

```
where TO_CHAR(entity.lt_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2001-01-01'
```

But you don't want to do that because that's going to force Oracle to evaluate that expression on the left side for every flipping row in the table, so it has a string value to do the comparison. (That's true unless someone created a function-based index for you.)  If you do the comparison on the bare column, using the `TO_DATE` on the literal side, Oracle can make effective use of an appropriate index (with `lt_date` as the leading column) to satisfy the predicate.

Comment: Just a note regarding the implicit type conversions in SQL where clauses. When Oracle encounters a predicate containing a comparison between a date value and a string literal Oracle will convert the string literal to a date literal _if it can_, **otherwise** it will implicitly convert the date to a string using the current value of the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session state value.  In this case the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is likely `'DD-MON-RR'` which doesn't match the '2001-01-01' string preventing an implicit conversion of the string literal to a date literal.