# Encountering SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

I created a table using this query 
`CREATE TABLE Store (id number(11) primary key not null, opening_time timestamp CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM opening_time) > 8 || NULL));`

Now, when I try to insert some data using `insert into Store values(1, '04/04/2012 13:35 PM');`, I encounter this error `SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month`.

What is it that I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I enter this date into a table using sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149206/why-cant-i-enter-this-date-into-a-table-using-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'04/04/2012 13:35 PM'` is not a date - it is a string.

Oracle will do an implicit `TO_DATE( string_value, format_mask )` on non-date literals when inserting them into a `DATE` column using the value of the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask (*note: this is a session parameter and belongs to the client; it is not a global setting*). If the non-date literal matches this format then it will work (and if it doesn't then it won't) - however, if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is ever changed then it will immediately break (any be a huge pain to debug as the code that was working won't but no-one will have changed the code).

You can find out your current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` with the query:

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE  PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

It is better to explicitly use `TO_DATE()` with the correct format mask or to use an ANSI/ISO date literal (i.e. `DATE '2012-04-04'` or `TIMESTAMP '2012-04-04 13:35'`).

You can do:

```
INSERT INTO STORE ( id, opening_time )
  VALUES( 1, TO_DATE( '04/04/2012 13:35', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI' );
```

*(you do not need the `AM/PM` as the hour component is already on a 24 hour clock)*

or

```
INSERT INTO STORE ( id, opening_time )
  VALUES( 1, TIMESTAMP '2012-04-04 13:35:00' );
```

*(using the ANSI/ISO timestamp literal which Oracle will implicitly convert to a date)*

Comment: What if I need the AM/PM? How can I format it? I'm using  `to_timestamp('30-03-2021 08:48:46 PM','DD-MM-YYYY hh:mi:ss.ff AM')` but it puzzles me as the PM and AM are different timing. One is in the afternoon one in the morning. (It does return the right query though., idk how.)

Comment: @aaa The documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Format-Models.html#GUID-D91AEB37-CE0C-4CC1-A412-020B8B7DEB38). Both `AM` and `PM` are the meridian indicator and can be used interchangeably in the format model.

Answer (score 3):

> SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month

`'04/04/2012 13:35 PM'` is a **string** and not a **date**. You should always use **TO_DATE** to explicitly convert a string into date. Never ever rely on **implicit datatype conversion**. You might just be lucky to depend on your **locale-specific NLS settings**. However, it won't work if the NLS settings are different. So, always use **TO_DATE** to convert a literal into date using proper **format mask**.

Looking at the datetime value, no need to use **timestamp**, simply use **DATE** data type. It can hold till precision up to seconds.

```
CREATE TABLE Store (id number(11) primary key not null, 
                    opening_time timestamp 
                    CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM opening_time) > 8 || NULL)); 

insert into Store 
values(1, TO_DATE('04/04/2012 13:35 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI', 'nls_date_language=ENGLISH'));
```

You could also use the **[ANSI date/timestamp literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ)** which uses a **fixed format** and therefore it is **NLS independent**.

```
DATE '2012-04-04'
```

or

```
TIMESTAMP '2012-04-04 13:35:00'
```

Comment: Why is everybody in Oracle-land using TO_DATE/TO_TIMESTAMP instead of a simple Standard SQL compliant literals? `DATE '2012-04-04'`  or `TIMESTAMP '2012-04-04 13:35:00'` don't depend on NLS settings.

Comment: @dnoeth I too suggest the ANSI date/timestamp literal. Here my intention as to make the OP aware of the data type. Anyway, always good to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to insert the primary key value in table. It is auto generated. And try to provide the format of your date using the `TO_DATE` function like:

```
insert into Store values(to_date('04/04/2012 13:35 PM','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI AM'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is using to_date function with your data format. 
In you case it will:

```
insert into Store 
values(1, to_date('04/04/2012 13:35', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi'));
```

More details about this function you can found here in [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#i34924).

Answer (score -2):

insert into Store values(1, '04-APR-2012 13:35 PM');

This works for me.

Comment: Oracle will do an implicit `TO_DATE( string_value, format_mask )` on non-date literals when inserting them into a DATE column using the value of the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask. If the non-date literal matches this format then it will work (and if it doesn't then it won't) but the parameter belongs to the **client's** session and is not guaranteed to be consistent across users.